# getting nil values for dateformatter

Tags: iphone, ios

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

 dateFormatter.dateFormat       = @"EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss VVVV";

 NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [df1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];

 NSString *dateString           = @"Mon, 29 Apr 2013 01:00:49 +0000";

 NSDate *date1= [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

 NSString *localDateString      = [df1 stringFromDate:date1];

 NSLog(@"localDateString=%@", localDateString);
```

when i am using constant dateString value it gives correct output .. where as i am give input from xml paring value dateString returns nil value

Comment: Need to check parsed xml value.... the value is **surely** not similar to dateString.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some additional whitespace on the beginning or end of your string.
Compare the lengths of both strings using

```
dateString.length;
```

and

```
otherDateString.length;
```

You could also compare and see if these strings are equal by using

```
[dateString isEqualToString:otherDateString];
```

which will probably return false.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible problems:

1. `VVVV` is not a valid field symbol. You probably want `Z`. See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns
2. Make sure your formatter is set to English (not default) locale, otherwise patterns like `Mon` or `Apr` won't be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that the Date String you are getting is not in proper String format so first you have to check it.

Try in this way:

```
NSString *dateString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourXMLValue];
```

Hope this will help.